# simple dynamic div panel not Loading in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am trying to learn How to create and Load a simple Dynamic Panel in javascript

here is My Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function createQuestionPanel() {
            var div = '<div>top div</div>';
            return div;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload=createQuestionPanel()>
<div id="d1" onclick=createQuestionPanel()></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On Debugging (on Firebug) panel is loading fine .I have tried every possible combination to call that method .But it is not Loading.. Div Panel is loading fine if static

I have seen suggestion to show / Hide existing Panel using style : visible functionality . and to use CSS .. I dont want to do that ..I just need suggestion that can it be possible in this way ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createQuestionPanel() {
       var div = document.createElement("div");
       var textNode = document.createTextNode("top div");
       div.appendChild(newContent);
       document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
 <body onload=createQuestionPanel()>
  <div id="d1" onclick=createQuestionPanel()></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a string. You're never actually interpreting that string as DOM Nodes, or adding the result to the DOM.

Try

```
$(document).append('<div>top div</div>');
```

Comment: He is not using jquery.

Comment: The question is tagged as jQuery, so I assume I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function createQuestionPanel() {
                document.body.innerHTML += '<div>top div</div>';            
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="createQuestionPanel()">

    </body>
</html>
```